# How to use prevState so I don't have to use a setTimeout

Tags: reactjs

How to use prevState on 'this.state.lat' & 'this.state.lng' so that I can remove the setTimeout from this peice of code below:

```
  getCords(authUser) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.firebase.cats().push({
        text: this.state.text,
        image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9',
        userId: authUser.uid,
        lat: this.state.lat,
        lng: this.state.lng,
      })
      this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
    }, 150)
  }
```

Without the setTimeout I get the incorrect values, so I think using prevState in replace of setTimeout should fix this issue? Any pointers are much appreciated!

Full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AuthUserContext, withAuthorization } from '../Session';
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  text: '',
  lat: '',
  long: '',
  address: ''
}

class AddCat extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...INITIAL_STATE
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // set Google Maps Geocoding API for purposes of quota management. Its optional but recommended.
    Geocode.setApiKey(process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLEGEOCODEKEY);
    // set response language. Defaults to english.
    Geocode.setLanguage("en");
    // set response region. Its optional.
    // A Geocoding request with region=es (Spain) will return the Spanish city.
    Geocode.setRegion("es");
    // Enable or disable logs. Its optional.
    Geocode.enableDebug();
    // Get latidude & longitude from address.
  }

  getCords(authUser) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.firebase.cats().push({
        text: this.state.text,
        image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9',
        userId: authUser.uid,
        lat: this.state.lat,
        lng: this.state.lng,
      })
      this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
    }, 150)
  }

  onCreateCat = (e, authUser) => {
    Geocode.fromAddress(this.state.address).then(
      response => {
        const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
        this.setState({lat: lat, lng: lng},
          this.getCords(authUser)
        );
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    )
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  onChangeText = e => {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  };

  onChangeAddress = e => {
    this.setState({ address: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {

    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Add cat</h1>
        <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
          {authUser => (
            <div>
              <form onSubmit={e => this.onCreateCat(e, authUser)}>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={this.state.text}
                  onChange={this.onChangeText}
                  placeholder="Cats Name"
                />
                <input
                  name="address"
                  value={this.state.address}
                  onChange={this.onChangeAddress}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Cats Postcode">
                </input>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          )}
        </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    );

  }

}

const condition = authUser => !!authUser;

export default withAuthorization(condition)(AddCat);
```

Comment: Ideally, just pass `{ lat, lng }` as parameters into the function.

Comment: It depends on the rest of the implementation, but you'd have to use something like `componentDidUpdate` or if you're using hooks you'd have to create a `useEffect` that has a dependency array with `this.state.lat` and `this.state.lng`.

Comment: I haven't used useEffect yet dam, will look into it thank you. @goto1 I have added the full code if you are willing to check it out.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, you're trying to do `this.setState({lat, lng})` and then call `this.getCords(authUser)` immediately with the new state you set through the `this.setState` call?

Comment: That is correct @goto1

Comment: So it's not `prevState` but the `nextState` then, just so I understand correctly, i.e. you want to call `this.getCards` with **latest state values**..

Comment: @goto1 Ah ok, yes that is correct also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208587/discussion-between-bennkingy-and-goto1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the signature of the `setState` method it takes an `updater` and a `callback` that will run after the `state` gets updated:

> setState(updater[, callback])

So you could call your `this.getCords` function inside of a `this.setState` callback, like so:

```js
onCreateCat = (e, authUser) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  Geocode.fromAddress(this.state.address).then(
    response => {
      // ...
      this.setState({ lat, lng }, () => {
        // call methods of your component 
        // that rely on latest state values
        // for `lat` and `lng` here
        this.getCords(authUser)
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Then, inside of the `getCords` method, you'd just do whatever you need to do without introducing "hacks":

```js
getCords = (authUser) => {
  this.props.firebase.cats().push(...)
  this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE })
}
```

Here's a quick demo:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-lehmann-8h7jm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I literally needed to do was add ' () => {' abd remove my set time out. Its working now with no hacks :D

Comment: Thanks a lot dude!